# php cURL transfer cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

How can I transfer these cookies

```
.adidas.de  TRUE    /   FALSE   1519852113  restoreBasketUrl    %2Fon%2Fdemandware.store%2FSites-adidas-DE-Site%2Fde_DE%2FCart-UpdateItems%3Fpid_0%3DBB2092_610%26qty_0%3D1
.adidas.de  TRUE    /   FALSE   1550524169  utag_main   v_id:015fe2df50a60014c3cedb252f0d04073001906b01978$_sn:7$_ss:0$_st:1518989969891$_prevpage:ACCOUNT%7COVERVIEW%3Bexp-1518991769885$_pn:3%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1518987220846%3Bexp-session$ab__doubleclick:TEST%3Bexp-1521580164884
```

to this style?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Cookie: mycookie=value;mycookie2=value2"]);
```

Comment: Get these cookies and create a string, what's the problem?

Comment: I don´t have the ability to. Can you help me with the style?

Comment: "I don't have the ability to." what does this mean? See [ask]. Specifically, you need to tell us what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you got.